# getting more than 1 value from turtle.textinput()

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, turtle-graphics

I know that the following code will give 2 variables

```
var1,var2 = input("Input 2 things: ").split()
```

but I am using turtle and to have an input in the turtle screen is with the method textinput(). I have this line of code, thinking that it would work:

```
var1,var2 = turtle.textinput("Input 2 things: ").split()
```

I'd type in "3 5" expecting var1 == 3 and var2 == 5 but instead I get, note that I have no idea what the entire error is about except for the last line.

Exception in Tkinter callback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 675, in eventfun
>       fun(x, y)
>   NameError: name 'var2' is not defined

Could someone explain how to get 2 variables from one input in the turtle screen. I only know of the turtle.textinput to get the text to appear in turtle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`turtle.textinput()` isn't a direct replacement for `input()` as it takes a another, initial argument, in addition to the prompt.  It requires a title for the dialog window:

```
> python3
...
>>> import turtle
>>> var1,var2 = turtle.textinput("User Input", "Input 2 things: ").split()
>>> var1
'3'
>>> var2
'5'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The split method allows you to choose which symbol to split by, so what you could try is to split by the space symbol, for example:

```
var1,var2 = turtle.textinput("Input 2     things: ").split(' ')
```

so if I input `3 5` then `var1` will equal to `3` and `var2` will equal to `5`.

Comment: No they won't.  You'll get a "TypeError: textinput() missing 1 required positional argument: 'prompt'" error instead.  The OP had this particular part correct -- you 'fixed' the wrong thing.